# What's this torque specification on the seatpost for?

Tags: maintenance, saddle, seatpost

I read 12Nm torque on my seatpost (a Cinelli Vai seatpost).

> What does this torque refer to?

I would assume it's for the two bolts above that tie the saddle rail to the seatpost, but at the same time it looks like a very high torque to me for those bolts, so I am confused.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest looking at [this table from Park Tool](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/torque-specifications-and-concepts#article-section-4) for what each component needs for torque.

For the seat rail binder (aka seat fixing bolt aka the bolts you've photographed), Park tool gives a range from 174 - 347 in-lbs as the Shimano value, with some others requiring as little as 44 or others as much as 300.

If we convert 174 in-lbs to N-m, thats about 20 N-m (the rule is divide by 9-ish). So, its a reasonable value for the bolts under question.

As noted in the table, the number doesn't really make sense for the seatpost binder (thing that holds the seatpost in the frame); you normally just go enough that it doesn't slip for that, which Campy suggests 4-6 N-m which is much lower.

---

All being said, I'm not sure who actually measures that torque unless you have fragile saddle rails or post or something. But I suspect many people go (well) below the 20 Nm ish figure from Park Tool by a good amount. I've never used a torque wrench for this,  but I'd guess I've tightened with 10 Nm at best.

Comment: The rail bolts on my *new bike* say 10Nm so that sounds sensible (the label couldn't really apply to anything else on mine). Also the seat post clamp could be a long way away at maximum extension.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, that table is a great resource! Compare to the values reported on the Park Tool chart, 12 N-m sounds too low now :)

Comment: @AlessandroCosentino - well, its highly dependent on the type. The single bolts are obviously higher, but even for the standard variety, there is a wide range.

Comment: That's for the saddle rail bolt. The clamping of the post in the seat tube is usually in the range of 5-7Nm.

Comment: @AlessandroCosentino: Be aware though that this the seat-post that you want to use with carbon rails in '21, the 12Nm torque is too high or the clamp isn't intended for carbon rails.

Comment: @Carel It's actually another seat-post, but with a similar torque.